# `The 'async' modifier can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8009)` error when using async in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, async-await

So when I try to add `async/await` in the react file, I got this error:

```
The 'async' modifier can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8009)
```

Does that mean I cannot use `async/await` in React or that is a problem of vs code or what can I do to enable it?

Here is the whole file:

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import {addOrder} from '../actions/orderAction'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class Dish extends React.Component{

    async handleClick = (dish) =>{
     this.props.addOrder(dish)
     localStorage.setItem("order", this.props.order)
     alert(`${dish.name} added to your order!`)
    }


    render(){
      let dish = this.props.dish  
        return(
        <div className="col-4">  
            <img />
            <h5>{dish.name}         ${dish.price}</h5>
            <Button onClick = {()=>this.handleClick(dish)} size="sm" variant="primary">Order</Button> 
        </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
    return {
        addOrder: (dish) =>dispatch(addOrder(dish))
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return{
        order: state.order
    }
}


export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(Dish)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can try either

```
async handleClick(dish) {
  this.props.addOrder(dish)
  localStorage.setItem("order", this.props.order)
  alert(`${dish.name} added to your order!`)
}
```

OR

```
handleClick = async(dish) => {
  this.props.addOrder(dish)
  localStorage.setItem("order", this.props.order)
  alert(`${dish.name} added to your order!`)
}
```

Comment: I fixed the problem with the second solution before. But thanks for your answer anyways!

Comment: With `handleClick = async () => e => {
    e.preventDefault()...` I get `Warning: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.`.  handleClick is called from a btn: `<button onClick={this.handleClick()}>..`

Comment: @Timo if you are using react, you are not supposed to invoke click handler <button onClick={this.handleClick()}> instead <button onClick={this.handleClick}>

Answer (score 2):

H\ve you tried this in settings.json

"javascript.validate.enable": true

Comment: Hi Jon! Where can I find settings.json? I searched for it but don't see it in my file anywhere

Comment: I'm assuming it is a linting error.  if you use vs code it should be within the .vs folder.  you can create one called settings.json and then:

{
   "javascript.validate.enable": true
}

Comment: I found it thanks! Then I add that to it, combined with what it originally looks like, now it looks like:
```
{
  "prettier.semi": true,
  "javascript.validate.enable": true
}
But still it gave me that error, what should I do? 
```

Answer (score 0):

For normal functions we put async keyword right before function name

```
async handleClick(dish) {   this.props.addOrder(dish)  
 localStorage.setItem("order", this.props.order)   alert(`${dish.name}
 added to your order!`) }
```

For lambda function we put aync keyword right before argument

```
 handleClick = async (dish) =>{
     this.props.addOrder(dish)
     localStorage.setItem("order", this.props.order)
     alert(`${dish.name} added to your order!`)
    }
```